# Setting a DynamoDB TTL for 2 weeks in future

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, ttl

I am trying to have a DynamoDB TTL called expire, be exactly 2 weeks away. I believe I am very close but have the wrong format for what is expected. Thanks!

```
const twoWeeksAway = new Date(Date.now() + 12096e5);
...
obj.expire = twoWeeksAway;
```

Comment: take a look at this article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-before-you-start.html looks like you need to configure dynamodb to use expire as expiration parameter and also it should be number like number of millis

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak yes, I configured it that way. I was just struggling to get it into number of millis

Comment: Take a look at the bottom of this article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-how-to.html they suggest ` Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)` so you can use same function for your twoWeeksAway date object

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [this page in the DynamoDB docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-before-you-start.html), refer to [this site](https://www.epochconverter.com/) for getting the format correct. It even has the javascript code towards the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but I will answer for those who need it in the future:

**TypeScript**

```
const TTL_days = 14;
const timestamp = new Date().getTime() + TTL_days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const ttl = Math.floor(timestamp / 1000);
```

Here's a print of the TTL field inside dynamodb.
[image]